# Service takes a long time to shutdown

Tags: services, container, kubernetes

I recently started practicing kubernetes on my local machine which is ubuntu 21.04L in a virtual machine (VMWare). Whenever I shutdown it is stuck for few minutes for containerd-shim with the following message.

[image]

How can I reduce the service time for graceful shutdown or is it some error?

Comment: I do not see an error.

Comment: but it is taking minutes to shut down